# faster way to calculate row values based on values of previous rows, pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

need to calculate value of the expression(as in code), for each row of the dataframe.
the current code works, however take too long to compute.
need a faster way to implement the same.

code:

```
num =0
den = 0    
for i in range(1,2000):
    p1 = p[i]
    t1 = tx[i]
    num = num * pow(numpy.e,-1*t1) + p1
    den = den * pow(numpy.e,-1*t1) + 1
    t["s"][i] = num/den
```

all values in the dataframe are of float datatype
above code takes approx 80sec for 2000 rows.
actual dataframe has over a million rows

please suggest.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `t` is the only variable you need to evaluate, you don't need `pow(numpy.e, -t1)`

```
num = 0
den = 0    
for i in range(1,2000):
    p1 = p[i]
    #t1 = tx[i]
    num += p1
    den += 1
    t["s"][i] = num / den
```

This would be enough.

EDIT:

```
def mytest(a, b):
    t = []
    num, den = 0, 0
    for i in range(1, 2000):
        num = num * pow(np.e, -b[i]) + a[i]
        den = den * pow(np.e, -b[i]) + 1
        t.append(num / den)
    return t

def mytest2(a, b):
    t = []
    num, den = 0, 0
    neck = pow(np.e, -b) # bottle neck
    for i in range(1, 2000):
        num = num * neck[i] + a[i]
        den = den * neck[i] + 1
        t.append(num / den)
    return t
```

Output:

```
%timeit mytest(random.rand(2000), random.rand(2000))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.26 ms per loop
%timeit mytest2(random.rand(2000), random.rand(2000))
100 loops, best of 3: 1.54 ms per loop
```

Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your (HUGE) 80 secs. You should fix somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks!, i folllowed your approach, in my code  t["s"][i] = num/den, was time consuming. so now saving into a list and then appending to the dataframe. works way faster.